# Determine length of audio file using DirectShow

Tags: audio, directshow, directshow.net

I am just starting with DirectShow.NET, and I am trying to get the length (in seconds) of an audio file. The audio may be .mp3, .wav, .aac, or .m4a.

Can I get this information using DirectShow, or do I need some other APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do this with DirectShow.  There are a variety of ways to do this.  One way is to query the [IMediaSeeking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407023(VS.85).aspx) interface on the graph object, and then call the [GetDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407023(VS.85).aspx) method on this interface.

GetDuration returns a 64bit integer value for how long it would take to play the file.

You will need to call the `GetTimeFormat` method to find out what units the duration is in.  The most likely default value is TIME_FORMAT_MEDIA_TIME which is 10ths of a microsecond.

IN that case you would divide the duration by 10*1000*1000 to get seconds.

You can also call `SetTimeFormat` before calling `GetDuration` if you want to force the units.

Comment: I tried this, and at first it didn't work. If I called graph.RenderFile first, then called GetDuraction, it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Judah: Yes, the graph has to know which file before it can tell you how long.

Comment: In retrospect that makes sense, but it didn't occur to me I needed to call RenderFile first, as we were already dealing with this particular file elsewhere in the DShow APIs. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Judah: no problem.  Its hard to know what you already know when we aren't actually looking at code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use get_Duration() from IMediaPosition interface.

This return a double value with the video duration in seconds.

```
    Double Lenght;

    m_FilterGraph = new FilterGraph()

//Configure the FilterGraph()

    m_mediaPosition = m_FilterGraph as IMediaPosition;
    m_mediaPosition.get_Duration(out Length);
```