# How can i show when playing a video file how much time left to play?

Tags: c#

For example on a label or in a textBox.
This is the code im trying now using DirectShowLib-2005.dll

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f = new WmvAdapter(_videoFile);
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(f._duration);
            MessageBox.Show(ts.ToString());
            int t = 1;
            const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
            const int WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x2000000;
            _videoFile = Options_DB.get_loadedVideo();
            FilgraphManager graphManager = new FilgraphManager();

            graphManager.RenderFile(_videoFile);
            videoWindow = (IVideoWindow)graphManager;
            videoWindow.Owner = (int)pictureBox1.Handle;
            videoWindow.WindowStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
            videoWindow.SetWindowPosition(
              pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Left,
              pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Top,
              pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width,
              pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height);
            mc = (IMediaControl)graphManager;
            mc.Run();
```

When i click the button the file is playing and i see first the duration in the MessageBox.Show wich show me: 00:02:47.4800000

So first thing is that the duration is wrong since the file play length is: 00:04:36 when im looking on the file on the hard disk.

My goal is to show some progressBar or without a progressBar for now just on a label the time left for playing the video backwards. If the duration is 00:04:36 so i want to show it go back 00:04:35 ... 00:04:34 and so on.

The variable _duration is long and i tried to convert it to TimeSpan.
But the video length is not the same as it is when im looking on the file on the hard disk.

This is the functin wich i didn't create just using it from the class WmvAdapter:

```
private void SetupGraph(string file)
        {
            ISampleGrabber sampGrabber = null;
            IBaseFilter capFilter = null;
            IBaseFilter nullrenderer = null;

            _filterGraph = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
            _mediaCtrl = (IMediaControl)_filterGraph;
            _mediaEvent = (IMediaEvent)_filterGraph;

            _mSeek = (IMediaSeeking)_filterGraph;

            var mediaFilt = (IMediaFilter)_filterGraph;

            try
            {
                // Add the video source
                int hr = _filterGraph.AddSourceFilter(file, "Ds.NET FileFilter", out capFilter);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // Get the SampleGrabber interface
                sampGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;
                var baseGrabFlt = sampGrabber as IBaseFilter;

                ConfigureSampleGrabber(sampGrabber);

                // Add the frame grabber to the graph
                hr = _filterGraph.AddFilter(baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber");
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // ---------------------------------
                // Connect the file filter to the sample grabber

                // Hopefully this will be the video pin, we could check by reading it's mediatype
                IPin iPinOut = DsFindPin.ByDirection(capFilter, PinDirection.Output, 0);

                // Get the input pin from the sample grabber
                IPin iPinIn = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFlt, PinDirection.Input, 0);

                hr = _filterGraph.Connect(iPinOut, iPinIn);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // Add the null renderer to the graph
                nullrenderer = new NullRenderer() as IBaseFilter;
                hr = _filterGraph.AddFilter(nullrenderer, "Null renderer");
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // ---------------------------------
                // Connect the sample grabber to the null renderer

                iPinOut = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFlt, PinDirection.Output, 0);
                iPinIn = DsFindPin.ByDirection(nullrenderer, PinDirection.Input, 0);

                hr = _filterGraph.Connect(iPinOut, iPinIn);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // Turn off the clock. This causes the frames to be sent
                // thru the graph as fast as possible
                hr = mediaFilt.SetSyncSource(null);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // Read and cache the image sizes
                SaveSizeInfo(sampGrabber);

                //Edit: get the duration
                hr = _mSeek.GetDuration(out _duration);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (capFilter != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(capFilter);
                }
                if (sampGrabber != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sampGrabber);
                }
                if (nullrenderer != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nullrenderer);
                }
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

The duration before i converted it to TimeSpan was in the variable _duration: 1674800000
I tried a lot of examples and stuff but i couldn't get far from the TimeSpan convertion.

How can i do it please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems related: [Determine length of audio file using DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205122/determine-length-of-audio-file-using-directshow)

The answer there states:

> GetDuration returns a 64bit integer value for how long it would take to play the file.
>
> You will need to call the GetTimeFormat method to find out what units the duration is in. The most likely default value is TIME_FORMAT_MEDIA_TIME which is 10ths of a microsecond.
>
> IN that case you would divide the duration by 10*1000*1000 to get seconds.
>
> You can also call SetTimeFormat before calling GetDuration if you want to force the units.

So in your case, I'd use `GetTimeFormat()` to figure out the units and use that to convert it to the correct units for a `TimeSpan` object.

Comment: GetTimeFormat need to get (out guid pFormat) what's that ?

Comment: In case you haven't figured it out yet, based on the signature you provided, you would call it as `GetTimeFormat(out pFormat)` where `pFormat` is of type `guid`.